# react.js firebase return a response object in error state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am writing a database wrapper around firebase for `react.js` as follows:

```
function withExistingUser( uid : string , next : any ){

    const bad = [".", "#", "$", "[", "]"];

    const isgood = bad.map( x => (uid.indexOf(x)===-1) )
                     .reduce((x,y) => x && y, true);

    if (isgood) {

        const res = firebaseApp.database()
        .ref('/users/' + uid).once('value')
        .then( snap => {
            if ( snap.val() !== undefined && snap.val() !== null )
                next(snap.val())
        })
        return res;

    }  else {
        // I need to return a `res` here
    }

}
```

I need to return a `response` object with error message of some kind in the last `else` statement, so that I can do `then` and `catch` later when using `withExistingUser`, otherwise I get a catastrophic failure in the app. A google search does not return how to create a `react.js` response object that I want. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding, you could do:

```
return Promise.reject({ error }):
```

Which would then give you the `{ error }` object when you `.catch()`